# "Passing" a variable to .html file using objective-c

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, video, youtube

I have a .html file in my project that I call when I initiate my UIWebView in order to autoplay a Youtube video. It looks something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
    <style>
        body, div {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="media_area"></div>
</body>
<script>
    var ytPlayer = null;

    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        ytPlayer = new YT.Player('media_area', {height: '200', width: '320', videoId: '9bZkp7q19f0',
                                 playerVars: {'playsinline': 1},
                                 events: {'onReady': onPlayerReady}
                                 });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(e) {
        e.target.playVideo();
    }

    </script>
</html>
```

As you can see it has the videoId hardcoded in there, so to speak. Is there a way I can have that be a variable and call it from my viewController? Something like

```
HTMLFilewithVideo: vidID;
```

Or maybe there's a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulating the javascript after the page loads by using the same technique that @samir suggested and put it in your webview delegate's method.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var ytPlayer = null;function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {ytPlayer = new YT.Player('media_area', {height: '200', width: '320', videoId: '9bZkp7q19f0',playerVars: {'playsinline': 1},events: {'onReady': onPlayerReady}});}function onPlayerReady(e) {e.target.playVideo();}"];
}
```

I'm not sure if the javascript like that will work as suggested (I just copied it blindly), but that's one method of doing what you want through a webview.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this by JavaScript function and then call this function with your `UIWebView`. something like this :

```
function javaScriptFunction {//Here you can access the html DOM and pass it the URL }
```

Then in your objective c code, you can call it with the `UIWebView` methode :

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```